# Убил btrfs (файловую систему) на SSD, теперь ноут виснет, когда SSD подключен

Tags: usb, железо, файловая-система, ssd

Завис линукс на btrfs - пришлось перезагрузить, соответственно, фс слетела. Проблема в том, что Диск в биосе виден, grub запустить его не видет, что пишет - сказать сейчас не могу. все вроде бы понятно, но странность вот в чем, пытаясь запустить Ubuntu или Xubuntu разных версий с USB получал зависание намертво при загрузке (там где логотип и кружок загрузки). Как только вынул SSD из системы - все стало загружаться как надо. Всё бы ничего и черт с этим диском, но там много нужных файлов, нужно как-то скачать их, как это можно сделать, если livecd зависает, а винда не видет его? И в чем может быть проблема зависаний? (SSD подключен в ноут вместо DVD-ROM)

Answer (score 1):

Попробуй подсоединить SSD к компу, в BIOS которого есть режим горячего подключения (практически все материнки на 1150-м сокете, но уточнить всё равно неплохо бы). Сначала прогрузи какой-нибудь линукс с флэшки\сети\диска, а потом подсоедини SSD. Переходник по совету @alexander-barakin тоже вариант. Если есть знакомые, у которых внешний винт Seagete GoFlex - попроси снимающуюся часть на время.

Answer (score 0):

скорее всего, получить даже хотя бы часть информации можно будет лишь с помощью спецоборудования.

но можете попробовать ещё один вариант: подключите диск в уже работающую систему через какой-нибудь интерфейс, позволяющий «горячее подключение».

например, *usb*, с помощью переходника [*sata-usb*](https://market.yandex.ru/search.xml?text=sata%20usb%20%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%85%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA)